# Is this a matrix of row echelon form? Or even the reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
In row echelon form? Or even the reduced row echelon form?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The key is to look at the definition you were given of (reduced) row echelon form, and see if it applies.  The answer is yes.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you very much! Yes, as this example does not include non-zero rows, so I am not certain whether the rule “if all rows containing only 0 are below all other rows” can be applied here.

Comment: Modify the rule to be "if all rows containing only 0 are below all other rows [assuming they exist in the first place]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Think of it this way: if it wasn't, then there would have to be a non-zero row in the matrix, which would prevent the matrix from being in RREF. Since there is no such non-zero row, you can conclude that the matrix is indeed in RREF.

Comment: Got that! Thank you very much^_^

Comment: @DannyC If this answer is enough for you to "get it" then don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @drhab Yes! Could you tell me how to accept it. I was new to this forum^_^ lol

Comment: On the upper left corner (right under the $0$ right now) move with your mouse. Then you find an option for acceptance there too, exactly under the option for downvoting.